# Json response with dynamic values on one of the nodes into SQL Server table

Tags: json, sql-server, api, t-sql

I have a JSON API which I convert into an SQL table successfully but one of the columns got multi in it and they are very different from each other. So how can I split the JSON value in the details column into multiple columns? for example Page,PageLink,Property,District.....

Here is my table with the details column which has multi values

| ID | ContactID | ActivityDate | EventID | EventName | Source | SourceName | details |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 23 | 223 | 2020-10-26 | 109 | BIK Pages | 18 | LeadGenerationForm | {"Page" : "thank-you","PageLink" : "https://*****/thank-you"} |
| 8223 | 1112 | 2020-10-12 | 118 | Request call back | 19 | Baitak Platform | {"Property" : "(TxxxxE-009","District " : "ddd","Price" : "22","UnitType" : "Plot"} |
| 8 | 1 | 2020-10-12 | 127 | liveturquoisecampaign | 18 | LeadGenerationForm | {"Source" : " Views","City" : "s"} |

Comment: So what are you asking here? The only sentence you have the is a "question" isn't actually asking anything. Putting a question mark at the end of a sentence doesn't make that sentence a question alone.

Comment: I have edited it please tell me if my question is still not clear

Comment: This looks like your JSON api is not handling multi-valued values properly, and as such is presenting them to the database as a single value.
You have two options: correct the api so it parses them into columns properly, or modify the incorrect data after it's persisted to the database.

Comment: On further inspection of your example data it seems like the "details" column is really just as dump of all the other stuff that might come along, which may or may not include keys which are unique to the particular row. This is much closer to the document type model used by NoSQL databases, rather than relation data.
You may want to consider putting this data into a details table with ID, KeyName and Value columns, which could then be joined back to your existing table via ID when needed. Each of the keys in the details would then have it's own row and have a 1 to many/none relationship.